# Remaining place in queue after closing hours in Salesforce chat

Tags: chat, businesshours

I'm setting up a chat solution for a firm right now, where they have opening hours for their chat service. The chat would tipically be open from 08:00-16.00. After closing hours, no customers should be able to enter the chat. Which would occur if no agents are online. The idea was to set every agent to busy after opening hours with an aura component. The issue is that if a customer enters the chat at 15:59 and is in queue, but no agent have accepted the chat; every chat in queue will be removed. Is there a way to navigate around this? That keeps every customer in queue when they entered the chat before closing hours, but allows no new chats after opening hours?

Comment: I believe there is no out-of-the-box solution for Salesforce chat business hours, see this [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dk59AAC). However, is it your question to leave the customers in the chat queue from 16:00 until 8:00 the next day (16 hours of waiting) or allow the agent to pick up the remainder of the queue that arrived before 16:00? Could you please update to clarify your question?

Comment: @JefersonChaves: We want to allow an agent to pick up the remainder of the queue that arrived before 16:00. Then every customer which entered the chat before 16:00 would be accommodated for.

Comment: Great, I get you now, that is a good question. I suggest you break it down with formatting to clarify for others who might help you out.